# Using Linked Server to store data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have a linked server setup on my source production server. I also have a secondary server which is the linked server. What I was looking to do is to execute a stroed proc and log connections to the linked server. However I seem to be having issues.

> The object name 'MetricDB.Baseline.dbo.WhoIsActive' contains more than
>   the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Metric DB is the destination server which is configured on the source server as a linked server.

I been using Adam's sp which was described by Brent here:
https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/

Due to space issues on my production DB I wanted to log it all to another server. Has anyone done this previously? or know if I'm missing something?

Thanks

Comment: To start, Adam Mechanic's stored procedure is `sp_whoisactive` unless you've renamed it. Second, as @filoo noted, you're going to have issues with XML and distributed queries, so it probably won't work. I think you'll need to run the sproc locally on your MetricDB server and insert the results "remotely".

Comment: sp_whoisactive is the SP and this is called within the stored proc.If you look at Brents link it basically outputs to a table but I want it to output to another server on a table using Linked server.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you try

```
EXEC MetricDB.Baseline.dbo.sp_WhoIsActive
```

Indeed, the name of the stored procedure is sp_whoisactive, not whoisactive, unless it is renamed, of course.
It could work...
Though it brings distributed query issue with XML for me.

Comment: Maybe a bit short for an answer? Could you expand on it? Maybe provide an example using a dbfiddle - see my profile for articles on answering questions. Also, you should use the formatting icons above the edit window to make your posts clearer. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: EXEC MetricDB.Baseline.dbo.sp_WhoIsActive - Don't think it works this way either unfortunately. If you try refenrece linked server then it complains about the name being longer than 2 where you normally have database.schema.table name obviously this has the linked server name too which gives the maximum prefix error